# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot project I'm working on, but am facing an unrecoverable exception when starting the application:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.0)

2021-01-27 20:31:16.477  INFO 35041 --- [           main] dev.conductor.centra.CentraApplication   : Starting CentraApplication using Java 13.0.5.1 on MacBook-Air.local with PID 35041 (/Users/shamil/Projects/Centra/build/classes/java/main started by shamil in /Users/shamil/Projects/Centra)
2021-01-27 20:31:16.478  INFO 35041 --- [           main] dev.conductor.centra.CentraApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-27 20:31:16.852  INFO 35041 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-01-27 20:31:16.901  INFO 35041 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 47ms. Found 16 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-01-27 20:31:17.003  WARN 35041 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut
2021-01-27 20:31:17.009  INFO 35041 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-27 20:31:17.017 ERROR 35041 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:617) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:767) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:572) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at dev.conductor.centra.CentraApplication.main(CentraApplication.java:18) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.<clinit>(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:62) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.initBeanFactory(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:82) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.setBeanFactory(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:65) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1810) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

As far as I can see, AOP / aspect isn't being used in the application at all, so I'm curious to see what requires the bean to be instantiated?

Comment: I wonder if this has anything to do with the structure of your packages. where is `@SpringBootApplication` and is it able to scan the packages that you have. I have sometimes some very weird exceptions also if I miss the point that you main class has to be in package (not directly in `src/main/java`) and all the dependencies have to be in sub-packages (at least this is the default)

Comment: Are you using Spring Retry by chance, if not directly, then transiently?  Googling, that seems to be what brings AspectJ into the picture for a lot of folks.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/147